# Jar File Added to ProGuard In Android

Tags: android

> I add poi-3.7 jar in my project. I vary confused about how to add jar in ProGuard.
>
> But My Exported Apk is created. But When Run, This Apk is crashed. Give me Solution.

ProGuard Code

```
   -keep public class  java.awt.**
{
 public protected *;
}
-keep public class  javax.swing.**
{
 public protected *;
}
-keep public class  javax.imageio.**
{
 public protected *;
 }
-keep public class  org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
{
 public protected *;
}
-keep public class  java.rmi.UnexpectedException
{
 public protected *;
 }

-dontwarn twitter4j.internal.logging.**
-dontwarn org.apache.http.**
-dontwarn java.awt.**
-dontwarn javax.swing.**
-dontwarn javax.imageio.**
-dontwarn org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
-dontwarn java.rmi.UnexpectedException

-libraryjars  /libs/GoogleAdMobAdsSdk-6.4.1.jar
-libraryjars  /libs/poi-3.7.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   Above code is right, but change In project.properties, 

   change proguard.cfg instand of proguard.config
```